# How to GROUP BY XML column

Tags: xml

First post here so hi!

I have used some XML in my SQL to split a string and this works fine.

When trying to GROUP BY after adding a calculation, I get the following error message:-
"Column 'm.n' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

My snippets of code are:-
TA.COST / COUNT(DISTINCT(WO.FIELD1))

LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)')))

CAST('' + REPLACE(
(CASE WHEN WO.FIELD1 IS NULL THEN 'UK' ELSE WO.FIELD1 END),';','') + '' AS XML) AS x

CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)

I have tried 'n' and 'm.n' but receive the following message:-
"The column 'n' that was returned from the nodes() method cannot be used directly. It can only be used with one of the four XML data type methods, exist(), nodes(), query(), and value(), or in IS NULL and IS NOT NULL checks."

I have also researched here and tried to use CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX)..... in the select and GROUP BY, but to no avail.

The error I get is: "XML methods are not allowed in a GROUP BY clause"

I can post the code if needed, but thought I'd sound this out first.

Many thanks in advance and regards,
Lex.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your full SQL statement, please? I think we need to see the whole thing, including the group by clause. Even better, if you could simplify the query to the bare minimum that shows the problem, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this works as designed:-

```
SELECT  WO.FIELD1, TA.FIELD2, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))))  AS COUNTRY
FROM
(
SELECT 
WO.FIELD1,
CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(WO.FIELD2,';','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM TABLE1 WO
) WO

LEFT JOIN TABLE2 TA ON WO.FIELD1 = TA.FIELD1
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

However, when I add the calc in the select, this is where it fails in the GROUP BY:-

```
SELECT  WO.FIELD1, TA.FIELD2 / COUNT(DISTINCT(WO.FIELD2)) AS "AVERAGE TIME", 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))))  AS COUNTRY
FROM
(
SELECT WO.FIELD1,
CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(WO.FIELD2,';','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM TABLE1 WO
) WO
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 TA ON WO.FIELD1 = TA.FIELD1
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)

GROUP BY
WO.FIELD1, 
TA.FIELD2, 
WO.FIELD2,
???????
```

Many thanks! :)